# Uninstall using shell

Tags: android

I want to uninstall the application using command in shell, the command is `adb uninstall com.example.android.softkeyboard`. How to execute command  using shell?

Comment: Add more detail.  I have almost no idea about what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Open up Terminal, and type that command into it.  Of course, if this is on Android, you will have to find a third-party program to emulate a Terminal.

Your question also happens to be ambiguously vague, so this is the best answer I can provide until you improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Just open a command line (cmd). Type adb to check if you have adb in your path-variable. If the command can not be found you have to navigate to your sdk/tools folder. There you can run the adb uninstall command. Of course your phone has to be connected and recognized.

Answer (score 0):

From the command line, go to your adt folder where the adb.exe is located.

type:
adb shell
pm uninstall com.package.name

done